# Adjusting resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix inside SpringMVC context

Tags: spring-mvc, resteasy

When I used Standalone RESTeasy through `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher` I adjusted

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Now I need to migrate Resteasy inside a SpringMVC infrastructure, but I can't find how can I adjust or cut the mapping prefix. Is there some solution to realize a `resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix` analog?

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've already found by myself

```
<bean id="resteasy.handlerMapping" parent="abstract.resteasy.handlerMapping">
    <property name="prefix" value="/rest" />
</bean>
```